# Android: NullPointerException For loop isn't working in doInBackground method

Tags: java, android, for-loop, nullpointerexception

I have an asyncTask and in the method doInBackground I have two for loops, one for each nodelist I have created. In the first for loop it works perfectly and returns exactly what I want. Even though the second is almost a clone, with the nodelist being the only thing changed, the application crashes.  What could be causing this crash?

Here is the for loops code:

```
                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_FUEL);
                NodeList nl2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName(KEY_FUEL);


                // looping through all item nodes <item>
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) 
                {
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(KEY_HIGHEST, "Highest units = " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_HIGHEST));
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexmap=" + map);
                    map1.put(KEY_AVERAGE, "Average units = " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_AVERAGE));
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexmi=" + map1);
                    map2.put(KEY_LOWEST, "Lowest units = " +parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOWEST));
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexmi=" + map2);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    menuItems.add(map);
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexmi=" + menuItems);
                    menuItems2.add(map1);
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexmi2=" + menuItems2);
                    menuItems3.add(map2);
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexmi3=" + menuItems3);

                    menuItemsString = menuItems.toString();
                    menuItemsString2 = menuItems2.toString();
                    menuItemsString3 = menuItems3.toString();

                }

                for (int i = 0; i < nl2.getLength(); i++)   
                {
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexnl2=" + nl2.getLength());
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    HashMap<String, String> map4 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    HashMap<String, String> map5 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    Element e = (Element) nl2.item(i);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map3.put(KEY_HIGHEST, "Highest units = " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_HIGHEST));
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexmaps3=" + map3);
                    map4.put(KEY_AVERAGE, "Average units = " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_AVERAGE));
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexmaps4=" + map4);
                    map5.put(KEY_LOWEST, "Lowest units = " +parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOWEST));
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexmaps5=" + map5);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    menuItems4.add(map3);
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexmi4=" + menuItems4);
                    menuItems5.add(map4);
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexmi5=" + menuItems5);
                    menuItems6.add(map5);
                    Log.v(TAG, "indexmi6=" + menuItems6);

                    menuItemsString4 = menuItems4.toString();
                    menuItemsString5 = menuItems5.toString();
                    menuItemsString6 = menuItems6.toString();


                }
```

Here is the error logcat:

```
08-21 14:56:25.611: E/Trace(1851): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at org.me.myandroidstuff.ComparePrices$asyncTaskCompare.doInBackground(ComparePrices.java:317)
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at org.me.myandroidstuff.ComparePrices$asyncTaskCompare.doInBackground(ComparePrices.java:1)
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     ... 3 more
```

Here is the nodelist nl2 length to show that this isn't the problem in the for loop:

```
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexnl2=4
```

Here is the logcat to show my outputs from the code. As you can see the first for loop works correctly but somehow on the second it stops before it should:

```
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi=[{Highest=Highest units = 133.1}]
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi2=[{Average=Average units = 128.4}]
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi3=[{Lowest=Lowest units = 124.7}]
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi=[{Highest=Highest units = 133.1}, {Highest=Highest units = 139.9}]
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi2=[{Average=Average units = 128.4}, {Average=Average units = 132.8}]
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi3=[{Lowest=Lowest units = 124.7}, {Lowest=Lowest units = 128.7}]
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi=[{Highest=Highest units = 133.1}, {Highest=Highest units = 139.9}, {Highest=Highest units = 141.9}]
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi2=[{Average=Average units = 128.4}, {Average=Average units = 132.8}, {Average=Average units = 136.9}]
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi3=[{Lowest=Lowest units = 124.7}, {Lowest=Lowest units = 128.7}, {Lowest=Lowest units = 132.9}]
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi=[{Highest=Highest units = 133.1}, {Highest=Highest units = 139.9}, {Highest=Highest units = 141.9}, {Highest=Highest units = 69.9}]
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi2=[{Average=Average units = 128.4}, {Average=Average units = 132.8}, {Average=Average units = 136.9}, {Average=Average units = 69.9}]
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi3=[{Lowest=Lowest units = 124.7}, {Lowest=Lowest units = 128.7}, {Lowest=Lowest units = 132.9}, {Lowest=Lowest units = 69.9}]
08-21 14:56:46.131: V/ComparePrices(1851): indexmi4=[{Highest=Highest units = 132.9}]
```

EDIT: full doInBackground method

```
protected String[] doInBackground(String...params) 

            {

                String urlString = newFifthString;
                String urlString2 = newEighthString;
                String result = "";
                String result2 = "";
                InputStream anInStream = null;
                InputStream anInStream2 = null;
                int response = -1;
                int response2 = -1;
                URL url = null;
                URL url2 = null;

                try 
                {
                    url = new URL(urlString);
                    url2 = new URL(urlString2);
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    return null;
                }

                URLConnection conn = null;
                URLConnection conn2 = null;
                try 
                {
                    conn = url.openConnection();
                    conn2 = url2.openConnection();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    return null;
                }

                // Check that the connection can be opened
                if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection && conn2 instanceof HttpURLConnection)) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                try 
                {
                    // Open connection
                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                    HttpURLConnection httpConn2 = (HttpURLConnection) conn2;
                    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpConn.connect();
                    response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                    httpConn2.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    httpConn2.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    httpConn2.connect();
                    response2 = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                    // Check that connection is OK
                    if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK && response2 == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ) 
                    {
                        // Connection is OK so open a reader
                        anInStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                        anInStream2 = httpConn2.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(anInStream);
                        InputStreamReader in2= new InputStreamReader(anInStream2);
                        BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);
                        BufferedReader bin2= new BufferedReader(in2);

                        // Read in the data from the RSS stream
                        String line = new String();
                        String line2 = new String();

                        while (( (line = bin.readLine())) != null)
                        {

                            result = result + line;
                            Log.v(TAG, "indexres=" + result);

                        }

                        while (( (line2 = bin2.readLine())) != null)
                        {

                            result2 = result2 + line2;
                            Log.v(TAG, "indexres2=" + result2);
                        }

                    }

                    menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    menuItems2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    menuItems3 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    menuItems4 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    menuItems4 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    menuItems6 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                    Handler parser = new Handler();
                    String xml = result; // getting XML
                    String xml2 = result2;
                    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
                    Document doc2 = parser.getDomElement(xml2);


                    // getting DOM element

                    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_FUEL);
                    NodeList nl2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName(KEY_FUEL);


                    // looping through all item nodes <item>
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) 
                    {
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(KEY_HIGHEST, "Highest units = " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_HIGHEST));
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexmap=" + map);
                        map1.put(KEY_AVERAGE, "Average units = " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_AVERAGE));
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexmi=" + map1);
                        map2.put(KEY_LOWEST, "Lowest units = " +parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOWEST));
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexmi=" + map2);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        menuItems.add(map);
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexmi=" + menuItems);
                        menuItems2.add(map1);
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexmi2=" + menuItems2);
                        menuItems3.add(map2);
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexmi3=" + menuItems3);

                        menuItemsString = menuItems.toString();
                        menuItemsString2 = menuItems2.toString();
                        menuItemsString3 = menuItems3.toString();

                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < nl2.getLength(); i++)   
                    {
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexnl2=" + nl2.getLength());
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        HashMap<String, String> map4 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        HashMap<String, String> map5 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        Element e = (Element) nl2.item(i);
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map3.put(KEY_HIGHEST, "Highest units = " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_HIGHEST));
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexmaps3=" + map3);
                        map4.put(KEY_AVERAGE, "Average units = " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_AVERAGE));
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexmaps4=" + map4);
                        map5.put(KEY_LOWEST, "Lowest units = " +parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOWEST));
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexmaps5=" + map5);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        menuItems4.add(map3);
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexmi4=" + menuItems4);
                        menuItems5.add(map4);
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexmi5=" + menuItems5);
                        menuItems6.add(map5);
                        Log.v(TAG, "indexmi6=" + menuItems6);

                        menuItemsString4 = menuItems4.toString();
                        menuItemsString5 = menuItems5.toString();
                        menuItemsString6 = menuItems6.toString();


                    }

                }


                catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        throw new IOException("Error connecting");

                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                 }
                //String[] combinationString = new String[] { result, result2 };
                String[] menuItemsCollection = new String[5];

                menuItemsCollection[0] = menuItemsString;
                menuItemsCollection[1] = menuItemsString2;
                menuItemsCollection[2] = menuItemsString3;
                menuItemsCollection[3] = menuItemsString4;
                menuItemsCollection[4] = menuItemsString5;
                menuItemsCollection[5] = menuItemsString6;


                return menuItemsCollection;

               }
```

Comment: null pointer exception mostly become because of a null try to get what value is null

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 14:56:46.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1851):     at org.me.myandroidstuff.ComparePrices$asyncTaskCompare.doInBackground(ComparePrices.java:317)`. Which exactly is the 317 line in your code?

Comment: @Daniel menuItems4.add(map3);

Comment: @Hasnain odd thing is the values arent null. If i change the values that i use for the second loop to the first loop they work perfectly and the ones that were working on the first loop dont

Comment: Where do you initialize menuItems4?

Comment: menuItems4 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: should i add the entire doInBackground method?

Comment: Yes please. Have you tried to debug the code and check the values?

Comment: yes if u check the logs i have added to my question you will see all the values i have them under indexmi. Also entire method added

Comment: I will run your code when I get home in an hour or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your initializations. You are initializing menuItems 4 twice.

Change this:

```
                menuItems4 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                menuItems4 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

to this:

```
                menuItems4 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                menuItems5 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Comment: i cant believe that.... wow im such an idiot... basic proof reading i was sure i had but maybe it was such an obvious error that i completely missed it. That was it...